# Adjust blur strength of Windows UI. Is there a registry key that sets the strength of windows 10s UI blur effect?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, user-interface, modding

I wanted to ask if there's a registry key/a way to patch the Window manager itself that allows me to adjust the strength of the blur used in f. ex. Windows 10s start menu.

Found a way to completely disable it but that isn't what I want. I want slight blur effect on my UI but not such crazy stuff as on Windows 10s task bar or start menu. No one actually seems to have tried this before.

Edit: I mean the effect where the Background gets blurred. Not the actual icons.

Comment: I mean the effect where the Background gets blurred. Not the actual icons.

Comment: Look at this photo https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=windowws+10&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn2.expertreviews.co.uk%2Fsites%2Fexpertreviews%2Ffiles%2F2016%2F10%2Fwindows_10_desktop_mode.png

i mean that effect

Answer (score 0):

Setting the blur effect to On/Off :

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`
- Create a DWORD item named `EnableBlurBehind`
  (if not already there)
- Set its value to `0` (disable) or `1` (enable)
- [Restart the Explorer shell (desktop)](https://winaero.com/how-to-properly-restart-the-explorer-shell-in-windows/).

However, this effect can only be disabled or enabled.
There is no known way to modify its strength.